# Databases for natural language query processing

Tags: database, yahoo

I just wanted to know know what all databases do Google, Yahoo or Bing use for natural language query processing. I mean they can take in so complex queries in natural language. Do they programmatically do the processing of our query and break down in some kind of hash and then map to result.
Please don't mind if the question is silly. I am just a newbie. I just wanted to know what all kind of databases are used for such purposes.

Comment: Google is hardly an example of natural language processing.  If it were, searching for "ping but not pong" would return pages with "ping" but not "pong".  It doesn't work that way.  Siri, on the other hand, is a lot closer.

Comment: Actually what I really want to ask is, what all kind of databases are used for such purposes.

Comment: I don't think you'd call them databases in the conventional sense.  You might want to read up on an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type Lucene OR
Type Solr OR
Type Sphinx
on Google or Bing.

You would then also come to know apart from indexing data structures something about stemming, thesaurus, synonyms, query expansion in search engines, metaphone etc. This all stuff would help you in getting answer to your question.

After you are through with above then later you can read more about establishing semantic relationship between keywords, collective intelligence, wisdom of crowd stuff that would help you in establishing similarity between say for example keywords like java and jee and jsp and servlets.